# What does 'cue' mean in this sentence?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

Source: [A kid held up a sign with his Venmo ID on ESPN and thousands of people sent him money.](https://techcrunch.com/2016/09/10/a-kid-held-up-a-sign-with-his-venmo-id-on-espn-and-thousands-of-people-sent-him-money/)

> Each Saturday during the college football season ESPN hosts College GameDay, an pre-game show with a bunch of football experts and hundreds of screaming college kids in the background.
>
> Today one of those screaming college kids was Sam Crowder, a student who brilliantly decided to hold up a sign with his Venmo username asking his mom to send him beer money.
>
> **Cue** the Internet, and instead of of getting a few bucks from his mom more than two thousand people sent him money on Venmo, including $50 from Venmo themselves.

[I checked OED](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lboOU.png) and there are many definitions for *cue*. I'm not sure how it is used here.

Comment: Context delackified: https://techcrunch.com/2016/09/10/a-kid-held-up-a-sign-with-his-venmo-id-on-espn-and-thousands-of-people-sent-him-money/

Answer (score 18, accepted):

It means ***enter***, from:

> a thing said or done that serves as a signal to an actor or other
>   performer to enter or to begin their speech or performance. - OED

Here the Internet entered the picture, enabling him to raise a large sum of money he could not get otherwise.

Comment: I was used as a verb and with subject (Internet) and the verb (cue) inverted, right? Can I rewrite it as 'With the Internet cuing, ...'?

Comment: No, because "Cue the XYZ" is an idiom, which means "And of course, along came the XYZ, which caused an effect".

Comment: In "*Cue the Internet*", Internet is the *object*, not the *subject*. Cue is a **command**, normally given by the director to the stage manager to cue a performer. Here it is being used figuratively, as if some invisible guiding hand signaled the Internet to become active in the process. Technically, the Internet is not cuing, but being cued. But you cannot say that, because that's not what *really* happened.

Comment: How does the grammar work if "cue the Internet" is of the form '<verb> <object>'? Is 'Cuing the Internet, ....' better or wrong?

Comment: @qazwsx *Cue someone/something* is an idiom. You cannot change it.