# Can the word "cue" be used to start a (this) sentence?

Tags: word-usage

Here's an example of how I'd like to use the word. The use is in author's voice. I've hidden the actual joke and replaced it with a dummy text since the joke would be lost here anyway.

> "Here, the robot makes a joke". Cue annoying robotic laughter.

Comment: What evidence do you have that suggests it may not be appropriate?

Comment: Yes, it can - see: http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/347969/what-does-cue-mean-in-this-sentence

Comment: @Jim no evidence. Just that I've never seen or heard it like that in literature. This is not a script or scene directions. It's a dialogue in a a story I'm writing. I'll edit my question so that it's clearer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the context you have stated (stage directions or a play script) your sentence is actually a fragment; and perfectly reasonable; as it is a subtext to the actual content.

In any other context, it would not be correct, but accepted. However, the correct way to state it is:

> Cue the ___________________ .

Or

> The director cued the ________________ .

Or

> The robotic laughter was cued.

Comment: The idiom "cue xyz" can be used outside the context of a script, too.

Answer (score -1):

Cue- being an action verb, a transitive verb -like kick-needs a direct object which is very much here in- annoying robotic laughter.
Maybe we used an article THE as below.
Cue the annoying robotic laughter.
And maybe please to end up or begin with.
Cue the annoying robotic laughter please.
OR
Please cue the annoying robotic laughter.

Comment: "Cue" is an imperative in what's apparently a script, although OP hasn't told us so.  It's like "Raise lights" or "Enter left".

Comment: I edited my question now :). It's not a script, but a fragment from a story I'm writing. So it's author voice.